# How to increase tabs count based on for loop index in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Following is my for loop

```
array=( one two three )

for (( i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++ ))
do
    echo -e "\t${array[$i]}"
done
```

with this script I'm getting the output as

```
#current output
        one
        two
        three
```

but my requirement is to increase tabs count based on index of for loop.

```
#required output
        one
            two
                three
```

can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( one two three )

for (( i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++ ))
do
    printf %"${i}"s |tr " " "\t"
    echo -e "\t${array[$i]}"
done
```

Demo :

```
$./test.ksh 
    one
        two
            three
$cat test.ksh 
#!/bin/bash

array=( one two three )

for (( i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++ ))
do
    printf %"${i}"s |tr " " "\t"
    echo -e "\t${array[$i]}"
done
$
```

Explanation :

`printf %"${i}"s`  --> will print space `i` times.

Answer (score 2):

Use an inner loop:

```sh
for (( i=0; i < ${#array[@]}; ++i )) ; do
    for (( j=0; j<=i; ++j )) ; do
        printf '\t'
    done
    echo "${array[$i]}"
done
```

or accumulate the tabs in a variable:

```sh
for (( i=0; i < ${#array[@]}; ++i )) ; do
    t+=$'\t'
    echo "$t${array[$i]}"
done
```

Alternatively, use Perl which has the repetition operator:

```
perl -E 'say "\t" x ++$i, $_ for @ARGV' "${array[@]}"
```